# How do I take the user input as it is given and not have it converted to the string data type?

Tags: python, encoding, cryptography

I have a key

```
b'-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIDCgIBAAKBpwYMzwEMAwLajdq74D0Q7NRXICJr/EZHI6z0NcmVbiAj139f7apO\nWG0KV9MJVjENFkh1Ld64B2GY8Ibq7/jCz/nPU67eQPmAKU59COzGK0+WSiDJ+twE\nLwH0eqzvC6DauDngw2biWIR6p/A9OHFXm2xANW1CPq64a/h9IFlXslOhHtwjfv8k\nN0mZ/PHK9vxWJlWwxEmI/sBXJlAa1fxxCl62H2N4YIvrAgMBAAECgacCOSrJY7Sn\nk9GVlH1vc4zU67+vZqeq2/HMWWJ61iNGRGWpNYONloUAbVChCUlXdUu/DPDybAaq\nYx3hNu1BKbZsQziphpuyFNsZMPHasWixMrXDHvTWUcEuOYKjk4EksDsCplo1BryY\n+O6kel711Xi6zVXEt/1aWc8s6KP1sIPunSbUh4m9BIPQzrQ6ImdgY0XtSqpIvw2I\n2zPFnRb2ZsMx7KgnXt1VlzX2g=\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'
```

I need to take this as an input

```
key = input("enter your key")
```

When I do this, the key is converted to a string.

```
"b'-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIDCgIBAAKBpwYMzwEMAwLajdq74D0Q7NRXICJr/EZHI6z0NcmVbiAj139f7apO\nWG0KV9MJVjENFkh1Ld64B2GY8Ibq7/jCz/nPU67eQPmAKU59COzGK0+WSiDJ+twE\nLwH0eqzvC6DauDngw2biWIR6p/A9OHFXm2xANW1CPq64a/h9IFlXslOhHtwjfv8k\nN0mZ/PHK9vxWJlWwxEmI/sBXJlAa1fxxCl62H2N4YIvrAgMBAAECgacCOSrJY7Sn\nk9GVlH1vc4zU67+vZqeq2/HMWWJ61iNGRGWpNYONloUAbVChCUlXdUu/DPDybAaq\nYx3hNu1BKbZsQziphpuyFNsZMPHasWixMrXDHvTWUcEuOYKjk4EksDsCplo1BryY\n+O6kel711Xi6zVXEt/1aWc8s6KP1sIPunSbUh4m9BIPQzrQ6ImdgY0XtSqpIvw2I\n2zPFnRb2ZsMx7KgnXt1VlzX2g=\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'"
```

Because of this I cannot use it for the purpose the key was created.
If I encode this key, the result becomes:

```
b"b'-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIDCgIBAAKBpwYMzwEMAwLajdq74D0Q7NRXICJr/EZHI6z0NcmVbiAj139f7apO\nWG0KV9MJVjENFkh1Ld64B2GY8Ibq7/jCz/nPU67eQPmAKU59COzGK0+WSiDJ+twE\nLwH0eqzvC6DauDngw2biWIR6p/A9OHFXm2xANW1CPq64a/h9IFlXslOhHtwjfv8k\nN0mZ/PHK9vxWJlWwxEmI/sBXJlAa1fxxCl62H2N4YIvrAgMBAAECgacCOSrJY7Sn\nk9GVlH1vc4zU67+vZqeq2/HMWWJ61iNGRGWpNYONloUAbVChCUlXdUu/DPDybAaq\nYx3hNu1BKbZsQziphpuyFNsZMPHasWixMrXDHvTWUcEuOYKjk4EksDsCplo1BryY\n+O6kel711Xi6zVXEt/1aWc8s6KP1sIPunSbUh4m9BIPQzrQ6ImdgY0XtSqpIvw2I\n2zPFnRb2ZsMx7KgnXt1VlzX2g=\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'"
```

Therefore I still cannot use it.

How do I take the input as bytes??

Comment: [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) will always return a `str`. a whole RSA key is typically not something a user should type... don't you want to read that from a file? (the leading `b` is not part of the key... you probably printed out some `bytes`).

Comment: I guess I can do that. Is there no way to take it as an input?

Comment: sure, you can. you have to strip away all the comments manually and then decode the base64 part. you'd need to do that anyway if you read the key from a file.

Comment: maybe any of the packages found on pypi might help: https://pypi.org/search/?q=pgp

Answer (score 1):

This is not an elegant answer but reading an RSA key from stdin isn't either so... As someone suggested in the comments, you should probably read it from a file. It would be cleaner, but hey you asked for stdin, so here is a stdin-based answer :

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

from sys import stdin

private_key = ""

for line in stdin:
    private_key += line

    # We need a stopping condition otherwise it will read from stdin forever
    if "END RSA PRIVATE KEY" in line:
        break

# We must validate what has been entered is correct (a regex would be better)
if not private_key.startswith("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"):
    raise Exception("Invalid private key !")

print("Here is your private key :")
print(private_key)
```

Enter the key as is, not on one line, and as said in other answers, don't include `b''` in your input :

```
$ python3 test.py
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIDCgIBAAKBpwYMzwEMAwLajdq74D0Q7NRXICJr/EZHI6z0NcmVbiAj139f7apO
WG0KV9MJVjENFkh1Ld64B2GY8Ibq7/jCz/nPU67eQPmAKU59COzGK0+WSiDJ+twE
LwH0eqzvC6DauDngw2biWIR6p/A9OHFXm2xANW1CPq64a/h9IFlXslOhHtwjfv8k
N0mZ/PHK9vxWJlWwxEmI/sBXJlAa1fxxCl62H2N4YIvrAgMBAAECgacCOSrJY7Sn
k9GVlH1vc4zU67+vZqeq2/HMWWJ61iNGRGWpNYONloUAbVChCUlXdUu/DPDybAaq
Yx3hNu1BKbZsQziphpuyFNsZMPHasWixMrXDHvTWUcEuOYKjk4EksDsCplo1BryY
+O6kel711Xi6zVXEt/1aWc8s6KP1sIPunSbUh4m9BIPQzrQ6ImdgY0XtSqpIvw2I
2zPFnRb2ZsMx7KgnXt1VlzX2g=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Here is your private key :
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIDCgIBAAKBpwYMzwEMAwLajdq74D0Q7NRXICJr/EZHI6z0NcmVbiAj139f7apO
WG0KV9MJVjENFkh1Ld64B2GY8Ibq7/jCz/nPU67eQPmAKU59COzGK0+WSiDJ+twE
LwH0eqzvC6DauDngw2biWIR6p/A9OHFXm2xANW1CPq64a/h9IFlXslOhHtwjfv8k
N0mZ/PHK9vxWJlWwxEmI/sBXJlAa1fxxCl62H2N4YIvrAgMBAAECgacCOSrJY7Sn
k9GVlH1vc4zU67+vZqeq2/HMWWJ61iNGRGWpNYONloUAbVChCUlXdUu/DPDybAaq
Yx3hNu1BKbZsQziphpuyFNsZMPHasWixMrXDHvTWUcEuOYKjk4EksDsCplo1BryY
+O6kel711Xi6zVXEt/1aWc8s6KP1sIPunSbUh4m9BIPQzrQ6ImdgY0XtSqpIvw2I
2zPFnRb2ZsMx7KgnXt1VlzX2g=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit as ShellCode said since key stream already contain new line characters this will make `input` to return prematurely so you have to either keep reading until end of key stream which means at `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` or read this key directly from a file.

```py
key = ""
print("Enter your key: ")
while True:
    key += input()
    if "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" in key:
        break
key_bytes = bytes(key, encoding="ascii")
```

this way you can paste whole key without problems. Also when you enter your key dont enter as `b'-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE (rest of key)` instead just enter key directly without `b'` at beginning and `'` at end of key(only enter the key data) like `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE (rest of key)`. So whole key will be

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIDCgIBAAKBpwYMzwEMAwLajdq74D0Q7NRXICJr/EZHI6z0NcmVbiAj139f7apO\nWG0KV9MJVjENFkh1Ld64B2GY8Ibq7/jCz/nPU67eQPmAKU59COzGK0+WSiDJ+twE\nLwH0eqzvC6DauDngw2biWIR6p/A9OHFXm2xANW1CPq64a/h9IFlXslOhHtwjfv8k\nN0mZ/PHK9vxWJlWwxEmI/sBXJlAa1fxxCl62H2N4YIvrAgMBAAECgacCOSrJY7Sn\nk9GVlH1vc4zU67+vZqeq2/HMWWJ61iNGRGWpNYONloUAbVChCUlXdUu/DPDybAaq\nYx3hNu1BKbZsQziphpuyFNsZMPHasWixMrXDHvTWUcEuOYKjk4EksDsCplo1BryY\n+O6kel711Xi6zVXEt/1aWc8s6KP1sIPunSbUh4m9BIPQzrQ6ImdgY0XtSqpIvw2I\n2zPFnRb2ZsMx7KgnXt1VlzX2g=\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: This cannot work as is because of \n. If you enter \n it will become \\n and if you enter a new line, `input()` will return

Comment: @ShellCode ohhh I didnt notice the ```\n``` you are right. probably this means that he must either ```input``` until ```---End RSA``` or store key in a file going to edit the answer.